# train_test_split crashing RAM when feeding with (big) numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

`train_test_split` method from Scikit-learn crashes RAM and kills execution  when feeding `X` with numpy array of shape `(5621, 224, 224, 3)` and `y`of shape `(5621, 3)`.

- X contains 5621 images of 224x224 RGB data.
- y contains 5621 OneHot encoded labels of 3 classes.

I was loading some images as training data to feed a Convolutional Neural Network, but when splitting into train and test data it crashes. Is there another option in order to load images avoiding this memory consumption?

Steps to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Generate dummy data
X = np.random.random((5621, 224, 224, 3))
y = np.random.randint(3, size=(5621, 3))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, shuffle=True) # Breaks here
```

I expect 3766 samples of train and 1855 samples of test as output, but it sends SIGKILL (and 100% RAM usage) and exits execution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is chrashing at Split-method or already before?

You can also split it manualy:

```
X_train = X[:int(len(X)*.8)]
y_train = y[:int(len(X)*.8)]
X_test = X[int(len(X)*.8):]
y_test y[int(len(X)*.8):]
```

Your data is already random, so should not be a sorting problem.

Comment: It is not crashing due to split method, but numpy array's size. I'va made some tests, and loading `X` and `y` arrays took about 7GB of RAM, so then callling `train_test_split` (generating another copy of them) reached to 15GB of used RAM, checked with Linux `free -h`